# What is the difference between multi-tenancy and multi-user solutions?

Tags: multi-tenant

I believe I understand this in terms of hardware, where multiple individuals 'share' the same processing and memory for their solutions.  But I've been looking at gmail and facebook, are those multi-tenanted solutions? Is it that as long as my solution can support multiple users, its multi-tenanted?

Comment: Related post - [Saas: Single-instance vs Multi-instance vs Single-tenant vs Multi-tenant?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54892681/465053)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can read [this post](http://multi-tenancy.blogspot.com/2009/07/what-does-this-mean-part-i.html) concerning your question.

> **Multi-tenant vs multi-user**
>   Any system may have multiple users. In a
>   multi-user system multiple users can
>   use the application (e.g. Exact
>   Synergy). The term multi-user does not
>   imply anything for the architecture of
>   the system. On the other hand, while a
>   multi-tenant system is a multi-user
>   system, multi-tenancy tells us
>   something about the architecture of
>   the system: namely that multiple users
>   share the same application and
>   database instance. Note that it is
>   possible to have a multi-user system,
>   which is not multi-tenant.

Comment: "Note that it is possible to have a multi-user system, which is not multi-tenant" Can you please provide an example.

Comment: @SandeepJindal : An example would be Slack vs whatsapp. Slack is a multi-tenant system, where slack runs the single (or a single group ) instance of application and data base servers and multiple users login to their teams(tenants). 

While whatsapp run on individual mobiles. It is just the multi user system and not multi tenant.